# Writing binary data to file in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm trying to learn C++ and I would interested in how I could write better code. The code should be independent of the architecture it is running on. What I want to do is writing some binary data to */dev/rfkill* so that I can change some settings. The target is an embedded system so the program does run with root privileges and the program is using the Qt framework.

This is the code I currently have and which does what I want:

```
    rfkill_event event;
    event.type = RFKILL_TYPE_ALL;
    event.op = RFKILL_OP_CHANGE_ALL;
    event.soft = RFKILL_ACTION_UNBLOCK;

    QFile file("/dev/rfkill");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        quit();

    QDataStream out(&file);
    if (-1 == out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.idx)), sizeof(event.idx))) {
        file.close();
        quit();
    }
    if (-1 == out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.type)), sizeof(event.type))) {
        file.close();
        quit();
    }
    if (-1 == out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.op)), sizeof(event.op))) {
        file.close();
        quit();
    }
    if (-1 == out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.soft)), sizeof(event.soft))) {
        file.close();
        quit();
    }
    if (-1 == out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.hard)), sizeof(event.hard))) {
        file.close();
        quit();
    }
    file.close();
    quit();
```

and the struct looks like this:

```
struct rfkill_event {
    __u32 idx;
    __u8  type;
    __u8  op;
    __u8  soft, hard;
};
```

The code is taken and adapted from the [rfkill](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/rfkill) program.

I've removed `__attribute__((packed))` from the struct because of the pitfalls mentioned [here](http://digitalvampire.org/blog/index.php/2006/07/31/why-you-shouldnt-use-__attribute__packed/).

I'm using the `writeRawData` function instead of the `<<` operator to write the data. The reason for this is that this code should work on big and little endian machines.

Are my assumptions correct and do you have any suggestions on how I could improve this code (besides not having any error handling)?

Answer (score 6):

First I would like to say that I'm not an expert on `rfkill`; so my comments are more general and may be slightly off for this specific case.

Despite the missing error handling (which you mention) I see only two problems. Not primarily with your code, but with your assumptions:

- You are correct to avoid `__attribute__((packed))`, but the reasons are IMHO not correct. The main reasons in your linked document are unaligned access, data size and performance. None of this is really a showstopper for your code, because you are breaking the data up into its primitive types. More significant is IMHO the simple fact that `__attribute__((packed))` is not portable. (Unless you remain on GCC only. On a microsoft compiler you would write `#pragma pack(1)`)
- I think you are wrong using the `writeRawData()` function. Because your code should handle both, big endian and little endian, you would *want* to use the streaming `<<` operator. I interpret [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdatastream.html#details) like this: `writeRawData()` will always write in the machine byte order - big, or little endian - whatever the machine is. The streaming operators on the other hand will do a conversion, when necessary, to whatever endianness you have selected with `setByteOrder()`.

  There is another advantage using the streaming operators, you do not need to do ugly type casting. Instead of this:

  ```
  out.writeRawData((char*)(&(event.idx)), sizeof(event.idx))
  ```

  you would simply write:

  ```
  out << event.idx;
  ```

---

**Update:** Error handling

I disagree with [user1118321](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/43196/user1118321). I [don't think that the QDataStream throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861298/when-to-check-for-error-when-using-qiodevices-blocking-interface-qtcpsocket-an) if it cannot write. I did not find anything about it in the documentation. (but the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) is known for having white spots) To handle write errors you can use the `status()` function. Or perhaps the functions from the underlying `QIODevice`.

```
out.resetStatus();
out << event.idx;
if(out.status() != QDataStream::Ok)
{
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: Undeleted by moderator :-) Nice answer!